# Lumen roLumen any route return 404

Tags: laravel

It works locally, but when uploading to the server, it gives a 404 error on any route. Generates 'NotFoundHttpException' error

Web.php

```
$router->group(['prefix' => "api"], function () use ($router) {
    $router->group(['prefix' => "user"], function () use ($router) {
        $router->get("/", "UserController@index");
        $router->post("/check", "UserController@check");
        $router->post("/store", "UserController@store");
        $router->post("/login", "UserController@login");
    });

    $router->get("/campaign-validity", "UserController@campaignValidity");
});
```

I'm using lumen as an api, so these routes are accessed externally. I will show the cors.php file

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => '86400',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
        ];

        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            return response()->json('{"method":"OPTIONS"}', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }

        return $response;
    }
```